# Jersey - dynamically picking resource method

Tags: jersey

I want to dynamically call a resource methods in Jersey based on certain annotation. For example if I have two identical resources in different packages with similar resource method like this...

```
package com.mycompany.controller.v1;

@Component(value = "UsersControllerv1")
@Path("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @GET
    @Version("v1")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getUsers() {
    }
}


package com.mycompany.controller.v2;

@Component(value = "UsersControllerv2")
@Path("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @GET
    @Version("v2")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getUsers() {
    }
}
```

Where @Version is a custom annotation which specifies the version of the api. Is there anyway I can intercept a request (possibly using a ResourceFilterFactory) which specifies a version as a header parameter and call the specific resource method with a matching version

If try this I get the following error at startup

```
12-Sep-2012 14:36:00 com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template /users for root resource class   com.mycompany.controller.v2.UsersController and the URI template /users transform to the same regular expression /users(/.*)?
12-Sep-2012 14:36:00 com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet initiate
SEVERE: Exception occurred when intialization
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:114)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any usage of the version annotation related to jersey. I don't think this is possible (if it is maybe you have a link to provide).

The URL patterns have to be non ambiguous (to each other).

If you want to provide 2 versions of the same resource, you have to provide the version in the URL.

However, you could set a parameter in the query, but it would then not really be 2 different versions of a resource, but 1 version responding differently according to an input parameter.

For instance :

```
@POST
  @Path("getUsers")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(...)
    public String getUsers(final String query){
....
```

Allows you to pass whatever you want to your resource.

Comment: @Version is a custom annotation I'll write and that will be processed with some Jersey filter. A bit more research tells me that I can possibly use a Sub-resource locators to achieve what I want - where the resource locator will extract the version no from the request and locate the correct resource with a matching version annotation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that you were willing to go that deep in jersey. Then The question is how you will overcome the check at initialization of jersey (as Jersey checks that it will ve able to route all requests to the correct method, based on the URL patterns)